# Error In Ajax Call In html

Tags: ajax, json, web-services

If I Run The Following Code It's Directly Go To Error:Ajax Failed And Error Show on Fire Bug [Reference Error: Ajax Failed is not defined"].
Plz Tell Where I Make Mistake....?
Its My base 64  Encode Value  For Name,Email,Gender,Password

```
var encodeRname = Base64.encode(name);
var encodeRemail = Base64.encode(email);
var encodeRgender = Base64.encode(lookingfor);
var encodeRpwd = Base64.encode(Pword);
var test = '.1!qkr*';
var decodertr = Base64.decode(test);
```

IT's My AJAX Call For Post

```
$.ajax({
    //https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/yyyyyyyyy/zzzzzzzzzzzz.svc/InsertRegistrationDetailsoverHTTPS?AuthToken={AUTHTOKEN}&RegName={REGNAME}&selGender={SELGENDER}&UserName={USERNAME}&UserPass={USERPASS}
    url: "https://www.XXXXXXX/YYYYYY/ZZZZZZZZ.svc  /InsertRegistrationDetailsoverHTTPS?AuthToken=" + decodertr + "&RegName=" + encodeRname +  "&selGender=" + encodeRgender + "&UserName=" + encodeRemail + "&UserPass=" + encodeRpwd,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/javascript",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (msg) {

    },
    error: AjaxFailed
});

function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
    alert("success");
}

function AjaxFailed(result) {
    alert('Error is : ' + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error handling function must be defined like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    //https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/yyyyyyyyy/zzzzzzzzzzzz.svc/InsertRegistrationDetailsoverHTTPS?AuthToken={AUTHTOKEN}&RegName={REGNAME}&selGender={SELGENDER}&UserName={USERNAME}&UserPass={USERPASS}
    url: "https://www.XXXXXXX/YYYYYY/ZZZZZZZZ.svc  /InsertRegistrationDetailsoverHTTPS?AuthToken=" + decodertr + "&RegName=" + encodeRname +  "&selGender=" + encodeRgender + "&UserName=" + encodeRemail + "&UserPass=" + encodeRpwd,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/javascript",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (msg) {

    },
    error: function (error) {
        // your error handling
    }
});
```

Comment: lionheart98 i try your above change in error function. now the  Error: Ajax Failed is not defined not come. But It's not Go To Success function...

Comment: Have you put a `console.log` or an `alert` to your success function for debugging? If it's still not work, send me your code.

Comment: Alert Not Worked Lionheart98

Comment: Does it appear if you place it outside your ajax request? Have you included the jQeury library? Any error in the console? Here is a working ajax example (just a different url because I don't have yours)  [jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/vbAq8/)